# Trying to append a function variable to document using this keyword

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to append an image to a div inside of an object ive created. 
So i have my object inside which im trying to append an element to a document.
The problem is: `document.this.Element.append()` wont work!

How would you solve this one?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, then accessing the `document` field in this way `document.this.Element.append()`, will likely be causing you problems.

The `document` field is globally defined in the browser context, and has no `this` field. This will mean that `document.this.Element.append()` is probably throwing an exception which is why your code is not working.

Assuming the `Element` field is supposed to correspond to your `<div>`, consider doing something like the following:

```
var Element = document.querySelector('div'); // Get reference to div element
```

Then, to add an image element to the div, you would make use of the `appendChild()` method like so:

```
var image = document.createElement('img'); // Create a new image element
Element.appendChild(image); // Append new image element to div
```

I'm not sure how your class is setup around this DOM interaction, however the following code snippet might give you some clues/pointers to help:

```js
// Suppose this is your class
class YourObject {
 
  constructor() {
   
    // You might initialize an Element field in the constructor. We'll
    // set this as the div element in the DOM
    this.Element = document.querySelector('div')
  }
  
  youObjectFirstMethod() {
   
    // In your class method, you first create a new image element like so
    var image = document.createElement('img');
    
    // Then assign your image URL to it
    image.src = 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/643157180594585601/dsaEOMIS.jpg';

 // Then attach the image element to the DOM. You can access the Element
    // field that we initalized in the constructor to attach the image to 
    // do this
    this.Element.appendChild(image)
  }
  
  youObjectSecondMethod() {
   
    // In your class method, you first create a new image element like so
    var image = document.createElement('img');
    
    // Then assign your image URL to it
    image.src = 'https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-wqo9oAoKa8Y/UJxVWogEp5I/AAAAAAAABfg/OeN6lWUcJ3g/s1600/Egyptian-Mau-Cat_Picture.jpg';

    // You can achieve the same thing without the need for a Element field 
    // by accessing the current DOM document directly
    document.querySelector('div').appendChild(image)
  }

}

new YourObject().youObjectFirstMethod()

new YourObject().youObjectSecondMethod()
```

```html
<!-- 
div is the element that your image will be appended to 
-->
<div>
</div>
```